# Enclosing curly braces around objects, reasoning behind it?

Tags: c#

I've seen some snippets of code do the following:

```
CalculateSum mySum = new CalculateSum();
{
  mySum.add(50);
};
```

while other developers do it this way (without the enclosing braces:

```
CalculateSum mySum = new CalculateSum();

mySum.add(50);
```

I understand that the first method ensures that the object is disposed of as soon as it falls out of scope but I thought that .NET garbage collector works well enough that you do not need the above.

Am I wrong? Is it still best practice?

Comment: Are you sure the first example is exactly what you saw? Wasn't there the keyword `using` in it? Right now, there's absolutely no difference between the first and second version.

Comment: [Is the usage of internal scope blocks within a function bad style?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200709/is-the-usage-of-internal-scope-blocks-within-a-function-bad-style)

Comment: Maybe You're confusing it with object initialization syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx